# Arrange dynamic list of buttons horizontally in dockpanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dockpanel, itemsource

I am using dockpanel to display a list of buttons that are read from an itemsource and want to display them horizontally but it displays them vertically.

I am using the following code:

```
<DockPanel Name="DockPanel2"  Grid.Row="1"   Visibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="260,50,0,0">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Foreground="MidnightBlue"
                            Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
           <ContentControl  Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
        </DockPanel>
```

If I use the following code (taking buttons as static list I am able to display the list in a horizontal fashion.

```
 <DockPanel Name="DockPanel2"  Grid.Row="1"   Visibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="260,50,0,0">
                <Button Content="Button 1" Margin="2" />
                <Button Content="Button 2" Margin="2" />
                <Button Content="Button 3" Margin="2" />
                <Button Content="Button 4" Margin="2" />
                <Button Content="Button 5" Margin="2" />
            </StackPanel>

            <ContentControl  Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
        </DockPanel>
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong.

Thanks,
T

Comment: You don't need the `Visibility="Visible"` part btw, as it is the default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the property ItemsPanelTemplate of the ItemControl and put a StackPanel inside it.

Something like the following:

```
<DockPanel Name="DockPanel2"  Grid.Row="1"   Visibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}"
                          DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Foreground="MidnightBlue"
                        Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
       <ContentControl  Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

Note, that I have removed the `stackPanel` just after the `dockPanel`.

Comment: This works. Except that  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate> need to be changed to  <ItemsPanelTemplate> else it throws an error. Many thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an `ItemsControl` does not generate separate items in the `StackPanel`, it generates the items in it's own "Panel", therefore you will have to use a `StackPanel` for the [`ItemsPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx).

I will provide you with some example code once I've tried it myself.

**EDIT**: I just hate you guys who simply take other answers and use them as their own, I guess I don't need to add example code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the ItemsPanelTemplate of the ItemsControl to be a StackPanel in horizontal orientation. What you have is just a StackPanel that hosts an ItemsControl - the fact that it is horizontally orientated is of no conseqeuence here. So try this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       </ItemsControl.ItemPanelTemplate>

       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate ... your existing xaml >
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanel`  of `ItemsControl`.

Example:

```
    <ItemsControl ....>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation ="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button .... />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found you can just create the element you want add it to a list and then use a VirtualizingStackPanel.

I use this in a foreach loop to turn my enums into a button list.

```
foreach (MyEnum myenum in(MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))){
    Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = "This Is Optional";
        btn.Content = "Content";
        btn.Click += CustomCommand;
        btn.CommandParameter = myenum;
        buttonlist.Add(temp);
}
```

I store my button list in an ObservableCollection.

```
public ObservableCollection<Button> buttonlist = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
```

This is the basic way I can execute the command based on the Enum value.

```
private void CustomCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyEnum parameter = (MyEnum)(sender as Button).CommandParameter;
}
```

And Then add them all to your view using a VirtualizingStackPanel.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding buttonlist}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Just sharing this as it seems dynamic and you can use it for any WPF element you can even make a mixed object List and the VirtualizingStackPanel will take care of it.